# Bash: What command can I use to redirect the entire contents of my current Terminal window to a text file?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, terminal

Lets say, I have a bunch of text in my Terminal session since the window was first opened (or since the last "clear" command was used), and exactly all of that is what I want in a text file.

Instead of manually 'selecting all' and copying from my terminal window then pasting into a text editor to take a "snapshot", what is the command equivalent of doing all this?

Answer (score 0):

it seems the script command may be your friend but you need to start that way: https://askubuntu.com/questions/216322/how-can-i-capture-text-from-a-specific-terminal-and-redirect-it-to-a-log-file-wh
or from man script
script  makes  a typescript of everything printed on your terminal.  It is useful for students who
       need a hardcopy record of an interactive session as proof of an assignment, as the typescript file
       can be printed out later with lpr(1).

```
   If  the  argument file is given, script saves all dialogue in file.  If no file name is given, the
   typescript is saved in the file typescript.
```

Answer (score 0):

This depends on your terminal emulator.

If you use KDE `konsole`, you can use `Save Output As...` in the `File` menu. (By default, no keyboard shortcut, but you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F10</kbd> followed by <kbd>a</kbd>.)

If you use `gnome-terminal`, you can select the entire scrollback using `Select All` under the `Edit` menu (again, no default shortcut). Then you can use the `xsel` utility (or equivalent) to dump the selection to a file.

`xterm` (at least, the version installed on my machine) has a `print-immediate()` action, which can be triggered from the mainMenu. By default, that sends the entire scrollback plus the currently visible window to a file named `XTerm` with a timestamp appended. The filename prefix can be set with the `printFileImmediate` resource, and the data saved is affected by the `printModeImmediate` and `printOptsImmediate` resources.

Alternatively, you could select all text and then use the `xsel` technique as above, but I don't know of a convenient way to select all with `xterm`.

See also: `man xterm` `man xsel` as well as the relevant documentation for `konsole`, `gnome-terminal`, or the terminal emulator you usually use.

Comment: I'm using the stock Terminal with Ubuntu, and I'm looking for a simple command solution, so this can be done easily and within a bash script

Comment: In other words, my bash script is starting with executing a "clear", it will run its thing, THEN I'd like to do a "save all text written on current terminal window into a text file" function at the end, which will of course have to be all automatic as an internal command.

Comment: @user3125996: You cannot ask bash to save the output from a script because bash has no idea what that output is. It doesn't intervene; when bash runs a utility, it hands the utility open file descriptors for whatever stdin, stdout and stderr are redirected to, and after that the utility reads and writes from those file descriptors. Even bash does the same thing; it just sends its output to a file descriptor. The only program which has a model of the "current terminal window" is the terminal emulator, and you communicate with the terminal emulator through its menus.

Comment: ... Of course, you could redirect the output of the script to a file. You could even use `tee` to redirect it to a file as well as sending to stdout. That won't capture any input from stdin, but perhaps there isn't any. Or you can use `script`, which opens a subshell through a pseudotty and collects the raw output, including terminal formatting codes, into a logfile. The formatting codes make the logfile a bit annoying to deal with, but it's possible.